# Trigger a grow-then-shrink animation on notification from ChangeNotifier in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a widget wrapped in a `Consumer`, that i want to smoothly grow and then return to its original size on notification from a `ChangeNotifier`.

I've managed to get the animation to grow, but not shrink again, so it just keeps getting bigger and bigger with each `notifyListeners()` call. I did that with an `AnimatedContainer` widget. I got the animation i wanted when i defined it in the `initState` method and manually calling `animationController.forward().whenComplete(() => animationController.reverse())`.

Any help to do that using `Consumer` as my trigger.

(edit)

This is the AnimatedContainer. The height and width aren't related to the value coming back from the state, but i'm using state.value ^ 0  just to trigger the resize. I know this will only grow in size, but thats why i'm asking how to shrink the sucker.

````
AnimatedContainer(
 duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
 curve: Curves.easeIn,
 height: _height * 1.1 * (state.value ^ 0),
 width: _width * 1.1 * (state.value ^ 0),
 child: SomeWidgetUsingTheState()...
),```
````

Comment: Can you paste your `AnimatedContainer`'s code, and maybe your `ChangeNotifier` if not too long, please ?

Comment: @MickaelHrndz AnimatedContainer added. The ChangeNotifier isnt doing anything particularly interesting, and the notify is causing the state to update.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Since you want to have some kind of "StaggeredAnimaiton", meaning animate between multiple values (here back and forth) and you are using the implicit approach by using `AnimatedContainer`, the following code could be used (not recommended though):

**My state / store**

```dart
class ContainerState extends ChangeNotifier {
  double height = 100.0;
  double width = 150.0;

  /// Needs the duration of the AnimatedContainer so we know
  /// when we can start the reverse animation (by setting the values
  /// back to normal)
  startWiggle(Duration duration) {
    this.height = 2 * height;
    this.width = 2 * width;
    notifyListeners();
    Future.delayed(duration, () {
      this.height = height / 2;
      this.width = width / 2;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

**Widget tree for reference**

```dart
class BaseView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Since we are using ChangeNotifier as our base type for
    /// indicating State objects, Provider has a designated Widget for that
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ContainerState(),
      builder: (context, _) => Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Title'),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0),
                    child: Align(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => context
                            .read<ContainerState>()
                            .startWiggle(Duration(milliseconds: 500)),

                        /// Gets rebuilded every time notifyListeners is called
                        /// inside ContainerState, therefore when we change the size
                        child: Consumer<ContainerState>(
                          builder: (context, containerState, child) =>
                              AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            curve: Curves.easeIn,
                            height: containerState.height,
                            width: containerState.width,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What you want to achieve here is not really suitable for this kind of animation (implicit animation). I would recommend to switch to direct animations using your own `AnimationController` instead so you have better control of how it should behave. My slides may help you here to get started: https://assets.kounex.com/flutter/uni_project_2020/en/04_flutter_animations.pdf

Comment: This is isn't quite what i'm after. I need it to grow and then return back to its original size all as part of a single animation

Comment: Updated my initial answer.

Comment: I agree with you that the animatedcontainer is not right. But i was unsure of how to get the animation controller to actually run forward when the Consumer receives the notification

Comment: You could get rid of the lambda expression (=>) inside the builder property of Consumer and use {} where you return the Widget - then before returning the Widget you could check for any value and start the animation there

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the caret sign is for. But I would do something like this :

```
animateContainer() async {
    value = containerSize;
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    value = 0;
}
```

Comment: where would i call ```animateContainer()``` from?

Comment: You can set a listener to the provider in the `initState()` and call it in there. Or you can put this function inside the provider and call it where you get the notification. In the first one, you need to wrap the two value assignments with `setState((){})`, and in the second you need to call `notifyListeners()` after the value assignments.